# Animating the frame of a UISegmentedControl

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I have a UISegmentedControl that I'm trying to animate the frame of using the following (simplified, but functional) code:

```
UISegmentedControl *seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", nil]];
[seg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 50)];
[self addSubview:seg];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations: ^ {
        [seg setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 400, 50)];
    }];
});
```

What happens is the size changes immediately, but the position animates properly. Why is it doing this, and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can work around this by manually resizing all the subviews of the UISegmentedControl inside the animation block.

Answer (score 6):

Tell the segmented control to layout if needed in the animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25f animations:^{
    self.segmentedControl.frame = frame;
    [self.segmentedControl layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. A lot more robust than fiddling with subviews.